# Testing for file generation

Tags: testing, promise, mocha.js, chai

I am writing a test suite for a file generation module. For example,

calling `generator('test')` will create a file in a specific directory named `test`. Here is how I set up mocha/chai tests.

```
let chai = require('chai');
let expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(require('chai-fs'));
let Promise = require('bluebird');
let rm = require('shelljs').rm;

let generator = Promise.promisify(require('../../commands/generator.js'));


describe('Generator', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    rm('-rf', 'frontend');
  });

  it('should generate a file', () => {
    Promise.resolve(generator('test', 'test', [])).then(() => {
      expect('src/test.js').to.be.a.file();
    });
  });
});
```

I am using `shelljs` to remove the file after each test. However, I am running into an error

> 1) Generator "after each" hook:
>
> Uncaught Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
>         at Error (native)

I think this is caused by the fact that `rm` is an async function, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

There are multiple individual tests for the generator, and I want to remove the generated files after each test. Is there a better way to do this?